# Is there a free alternative to Comic Life?

Tags: software-recommendation, free, comics

I am looking for an alternative to Comic Life. The main feature is to make comics out of your photos:

> Easily create amazing Comics, picture albums and how-to-guides using
>   your digital photos on your Mac or PC.

Are there any free alternatives (for any operating system)?

http://plasq.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There don't seem to be many alternatives to Comic Life, however there is one web-based alternative called Comiqs:

http://comiqs.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is also a free web based comic service called [Toondoo](http://www.toondoo.com/). Haven't used it for a few years, but from memory you can upload your own images or use their prebuilt cartoon characters.

Answer (score 0):

try this website: https://www.fotojet.com/apps/?entry=collage&category=comic it is kind of simular. another option is canva: https://www.canva.com/ canva is an online poster maker-it is not officially for comics but works fine. it has many posters with different rectangular dimensions. you can use a poster to create a graphic novel because the website is very flexible. you are able to import images, so don't feel forced to buy any premium images-there are millons of pngs and jpgs on the web. to create your own drawing of characters (or other things to add), you can use google drawings. (to get there, go to your drive and press new --> more --> google drawing.